# Android Stack Exchange App doesnt let me open questions in my feed that link to a per site meta discussion

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I receive a notification of a new meta post on the site I moderate, this appears in my feed. However, when I attempt to open this post, the application reports that it can't find the question.

This is how the new topic appears in my feed:

[image: Meta topic in feed]

When I select that topic, this is the error I get:

[image: Failed to load question]

Comment: I think it is related to the rename of Mods.SE to CB.SE. Notifications from other metas are loading just fine.

Comment: Affects only CB for me on iOS. Note that it doesn't work when directly accessing a question; when I load the questions feed for Meta CB it throws a similar error.

Comment: @Andy It is only related to CB, I checked it.

Answer (score 4):

This will be fixed as of build 2782 (it affects Computer Graphics Meta too).

Edit: This works now. You need to clear the app's cached data first.

Comment: So you also work on the android app? Thought Kasra is the only one working on it... cheers! :)

Comment: No, I don't work on the Android App, but the root cause has to do with the `ApiSiteParameter`. If you look at the `/sites` API, you'll notice that the current `api_site_parameter` is busted for Community Building Meta and Computer Graphics Meta.

Comment: oh, so it was API bug - makes sense.